# How do i add cart page for my ecommerce app on flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im using firebase as a backend. I retrieved products from firebase using stream builder .I looked into providers but all the tutorials used providers for the products page too.Can i use provviders only for cart?How do i do it?Or is there any other way to implement cart page?
here's the code for the products page.

```
class Shop extends StatefulWidget {

  final User currentUser;
  final String prodId;
  final String onwerId;
  Shop({ this.currentUser,
    this.prodId,

    this.onwerId});

  @override
  _ShopState createState() => _ShopState( prodId: this.prodId,ownerId:this.onwerId);
}

class _ShopState extends State<Shop> {
 final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String postOrientation = "grid";
  String shopOrientation = "grid";
  bool isFollowing = false;
  bool isLoading = false;
  String uid="";
  String prodId;
  String ownerId;
  Prod products;
  _ShopState({
    this.prodId, this.products,this.ownerId,
  });
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
          title: Text(   'Shop',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily :"MajorMonoDisplay",
                fontSize:  35.0 ,
                color: Colors.white),),
          iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: kSecondaryColor),
        ),
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,

        body:StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collectionGroup("userProducts").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return circularProgress();
              } else {
                return new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                      return new ShopItem(
                        shopmediaUrl: ds['shopmediaUrl'],
                        productname: ds['productname'],
                        price: ds['price'],
                        photoUrl: ds['photoUrl'],
                        username: ds['username'],
                        prodId: ds['prodId'],
                        userId: ds['userId'],
                        ownerId: ds['ownerId'],
                      );
                    }
                );
              }
            }
        ),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
          onPressed: ()
          async{ Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Uploadecom(currentUser: currentUser, )));
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add_box),
        ),
      );
  }
}
class ShopItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String username;
  final String prodId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String shopmediaUrl;
  final String productname;
  final String price;
  final String userId;

  ShopItem({
    this.ownerId,
    this.prodId,
    this.shopmediaUrl,
    this.username,
    this.photoUrl,
    this.price,
    this.productname,
    this.userId,
  });

  showProduct(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ProductScreen(
          prodId: prodId,
          userId: ownerId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    configureshopmediaPreview(context);
    return
//
      Column( children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child:Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
//                                width: 360,
                      height: 400.0,

                      child:AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        child:Container(

                          child: DecoratedBox(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                      shopmediaUrl),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ),
                    ),
                    ),
                  )],

              ),


            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              left: 10,
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                child: cachedNetworkImage(photoUrl),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 20,
              left: 60,
              child: Container(
                child: Text(username,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),

              ),
            ),


            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child:  Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: GFButton(
                  onPressed: () => showProduct(context) ,
                  text: "More",
                  icon: Icon(Icons.card_travel),
                  shape: GFButtonShape.pills,

                ),
              ),
            ),

          ],

        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text(productname,style: TextStyle(color: kText,fontSize: 30.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(  child: Text('₹',style: TextStyle(color: kText,)),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text(price,style: TextStyle(color: kText,fontSize: 20.0,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),
            ),

          ],
        ),
        Divider(color: kGrey,),
      ],

      );

  }
}
```

Comment: You can create a provider to achieve this task or you can do it using Blocs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use provider(or any state management solution) for the cart page only, but you have to persist those cart products so when the user logs out or exit your app and returns he will find his cart products still available, for persisting I suggest creating a carts collection in your Firestore and for every user create a cart.

Comment: Thanks!!. Should get the document id of the product when the user clicks on add to cart? How do I get the document id and it's details to save to carts collection?

Comment: you cart collection in Firestore should have only the 'prodId' and every time the user adds an item to cart you can add it to that as a document  and vice-versa for deleting.

Comment: every time you want to fetch the cart data you will get a list of product Ids so you need to translate that to usable product list, hopefully you understood me well.

Comment: Thankyou so much.now i have problem.When the user clicks on add to cart button i want the user to select some size of the garment.if you see some ecommerce apps it prompts size or color required to be selected.How do i add that required parameter with FloatingActionButton?

Comment: there are multiple ways to do so: first, you can direct them to a new page where they'll be able to choose or you can just use a simple alert dialog when submitting the form.

Comment: hey bro can you help me with this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591107/how-do-i-create-a-timeline-feed-using-firebase-in-flutter