# How do i create a timeline feed using firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
- posts
    - userID
    - userID
          - randomID
          - randomID
- followers
    - personB userid
          - personA userid
- following 
    - personA userid
          - personB userid
```

This is how my firebase collection is organized.

how do i get create a timeline feed for current logged-in user where the timline posts should be of only from the logged-in user's  following list?
Note:I dont want to use firebase functions.Is it possible with CRUD?
What ive tried so far.

```
 getFollowing() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followersRef
        .document(currentUser.id)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      followingList = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.documentID).toList();
      print(followingList);
    });
  }
  getTimeline()async{
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postsRef
        .document(followingList)//getting an error here saying list<string> csn't be assigned to string.
        .collection('userPosts')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();
    List<Post> posts =
    snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
    setState(() {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you share the code i'll edit it and send

Comment: @Niteesh    I'm not getting an idea on how to connect two collections(followoing and posts).If you give me an idea,illtry with code and get back to you.Should i copy a user's posts and save it into another collection for timeline feed ?Is that possible?

Comment: first fetch the userids of following list, then using the  userids fetch the post of each user

Comment: i tried that but im getting an error saying list<string> cant be assigned to string.I've edited my question and entered the code I've tried.

Comment: The thing is document accepts only string parameter not list

Comment: @Henok    any solution on that or a different apprach to get what i want?

Comment: An ideal approach would be making posts its own collection and each document for each post, then adding followers array (as field) for each post ( array contains the followers of the poster user ) and then you can filter your query using 'array-contains'  for the current user name inside the array we created, brings all posts which the user is added as a follower to the post.

Comment: I will post a more detailed form of the approach with sample code as an answer if you are interested in it.

Comment: will that approach not exceed document limit?How to update the array for every post for a new follower?It can only done to one document at a time right?

Comment: @Henok Yes I'm interested.

Comment: it wont reach limit because the old posts before will not be visible for the new followers only the new ones, if user has 100 posts and if you follow after the 70 you will only see the 30 posts that the user adds after you follow

Comment: I will post as an answer with further explanation.

Comment: @AugustTempa you are welcome, I posted an answer read it and comment on it if there are any doubts.

Comment: can you explain how the posts collection is structured, based on that i can give a solution

Comment: @Niteesh The 'posts' collection has user documents.Under user documents there's a subcollection called 'userPosts'.Under 'userPosts' post documents are saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List timelinePosts =[];


getFollowing() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followersRef
        .document(currentUser.id)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      followingList = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.documentID).toList();
      print(followingList);
    });
  }

getTimeline()async{

List posts = [];
   for( int i=0; i< followingList.length; i++)
{
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postsRef
        .collections('posts/${followingList[i]}/userPosts')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();
    posts+= snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) => {'id':doc.documentID,...doc.data}).toList();
}
    setState(() {
      timelinePosts = timeLinePosts + posts;
    });
  }
```

then u can use Listview.builder() on timelinePosts,
However this is not the most efficient method, since you are fetching all the posts at once. You can also implement fetch post as you scroll through the list, using Listview controller attribute

Comment: @August Glad to help

Comment: are you on flutter's dicord server?

Comment: we would like to have people like you there.  https://discord.gg/8ct9ef

Comment: `posts= snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) => {'id':doc.documentID,...doc.data}).toList();`can't be assigned to quesysnapshot and timelinePosts returned null .Anyway i changed the whole code andn made it work.Did you join the discord server?

Comment: Whats your user name?I guess i haven't seen that active there

Comment: Niteesh#8546, yes bit busy

Comment: Hi i tried pagination as you said it would make it more efficient.I tried but it doesnt data.Can you please help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62924101/flutter-pagination-with-firebase-not-working-for-me

Comment: `List <Post>Posts = [];  getTimeline()async{

            List <Post>Posts = [];
            for( int i=0; i< followingList.length; i++)
            {
              QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
                  .collection('posts/${followingList[i]}/userPosts')
                  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                  .getDocuments();
              Posts=  snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
            }
            setState(() {

              this.posts =  Posts;
            });
          }`Why posts empty?

Comment: @AugustTempa i forgot to put a '+' concatenation operator, edited the code, it should work now

Comment: @AugustTempa `List <Post>Posts = [];  getTimeline()async{              List <Post>Posts = [];             for( int i=0; i< followingList.length; i++)             {               QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance                   .collection('posts/${followingList[i]}/userPosts')                   .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)                   .getDocuments();               Posts+=  snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();             }             setState(() {                this.posts =  Posts;             });           }`

Comment: it should work work unless the collection path is wrong or there's problem in fetching the following list. Can you share a screenshot of the structure of userFollowing collection and posts collection and may be you can share the github link of the project.

Answer (score 2):

The approach which I think is efficient is using A collection 'Posts' and document for each post, with an array inside the post document as a field.

This means when a user adds post you have to include the user's followers as a field(List<dynamic) inside the post.

```
- posts(Collection)

    - post(Document)
 
         - followers(List<dynamic>)
```

you can query post for users like

```
Firestore.instance.collection('posts').where('followers', arrayContains: currentUserId).snapshots();
//this brings all queries with the tagged users as followers aka the users that follow the poster will be able to query this post.
```

if you want to update the array you can use

> FieldValue.arrayRemove or FieldValue.arrayUnion,

Edit: As a final warning I must mention that there is a limit to how much data there could be for one document, based on the scale of your app you have to decide whether **to put a growing list (such as followers) inside one document** or **to create another collection for the growing list and give one document for each element** since documents can't be limited (this approach could cost more).