# Flutter pagination with firebase not working for me

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried two posibilities but the firebase data isnt being stored in the products list.The app page returns no data as there is nothing in procucts list. foollowing list returns data succesfully.The second possibilty that i tried and the Consolelog is  in this pastebin link below:
https://pastebin.com/DM47YHY6

```
         List<String> foollowingList = [];
List<NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];
List<DocumentSnapshot> products = []; // stores fetched products
bool isLoading = true; // track if products fetching
bool hasMore = true; // flag for more products available or not
int documentLimit = 10; // documents to be fetched per request
DocumentSnapshot lastDocument; // flag for last document from where next 10 records to be fetched
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController(); /
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getFfollowing();
  getPosts();
  _scrollController.addListener(() {
    double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20;
    if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
      getMorePosts();
    }
  });

}
getFfollowing() async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followingRef
      .document(currentUser.id)
      .collection('userFollowing')
      .getDocuments();
  setState(() {
    foollowingList = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.documentID).toList();
  });
}

getPosts()async{

  for( int i=0; i< foollowingList.length; i++) {
    Query q  =  Firestore.instance
        .collection('posts/${foollowingList[i]}/userPosts')
        .orderBy('ownerId')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(documentLimit);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await q.getDocuments();

    print("kjndskjl$products");
    lastDocument = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.documents.length - 1];
    products = querySnapshot.documents;
    setState(() {

      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

}
getMorePosts()async{
  print('get more called');
  if(hasMore == false){
    return;
  } if(hasMore == true){
    return;
  }
  hasMore = true;
  for( int i=0; i< foollowingList.length; i++) {
        Query q = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('posts/${foollowingList[i]}/userPosts')
          .orderBy('ownerId')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(lastDocument)
          .limit(documentLimit);
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await q.getDocuments();
        if (querySnapshot.documents.length == 0) {
          hasMore = false;
        }
        lastDocument = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.documents.length - 1];
        products.addAll(querySnapshot.documents);
        setState(() {
          hasMore = false;
    print(products);
        });
  }


}

buildPosts(){
  return
    Column(children: [
      Expanded(
        child: products.length == 0
            ? Center(
          child: Text('No Data...'),
        )
            : ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          itemCount: products.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return
              FutureBuilder(
                future: usersRef.document(products[index].data['ownerId']).get(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return circularProgress();
                  }
                  User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
                  return Column(children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => showProfile(context, profileId: user.id),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => showProfile(context, profileId: user.id),
                        child: Text(
                          user.displayName,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: kText,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => showProfile(context, profileId: user.id),
                        child: Text(user.username,
                          style: TextStyle(color: kIcon),),
                      ),),
                    cachedNetworkImage(products[index].data['mediaUrl']),

                    Divider(color: kGrey,),
                  ],

                  );
                },
              );
```

[image]![

Answer (score 1):

In your first code

```
getMorePosts()async{
  print('get more called');
  if(hasMore == false){
    return;
  } if(hasMore == true){
    return;
  }
  //The rest is dead code, you always return if hasMore is true or false
  ....
}
```

In your Snippet it seems it actually fills the prodcuts list but user is null `(The getter 'id' was called on null)`, are you sure `User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);` is parsing the data correctly? try changing `showProfile(context, profileId: user?.id ?? 1)` just to test it (I don't know if id should be an int, String, etc but in case of String change the 1 with some String 'Test')

**UPDATE**

Instead of running getPost in `initState` run it at the end of `getFfollowing`

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getFfollowing();
  //getPosts(); this could run after getFfollowing ends, where the list is empty
  _scrollController.addListener(() {
    double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20;
    if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
      getMorePosts();
    }
  });
}

getFfollowing() async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followingRef
      .document(currentUser.id)
      .collection('userFollowing')
      .getDocuments();
  setState(() {
    foollowingList = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.documentID).toList();
  });
  if(foollowingList.isNotEmpty) await getPosts(); //run it here when you're sure the future is completed and the list is full
}
```

The trick is that initState cannot run a Future, so it will try to run `getFfollowing` and `getPosts` in the order they're called, but putting `getPosts` inside `getFfollowing`, which is async, assure you that it will run only when the other code ends. Also try to avoid using setState inside the for, this will make it rebuild a lot of times unnecesary, just put it at the beginning and end

```
getPosts()async{
  setState(() => isLoading = true);
  for( int i=0; i< foollowingList.length; i++) {
    Query q  =  Firestore.instance
        .collection('posts/${foollowingList[i]}/userPosts')
        .orderBy('ownerId')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(documentLimit);
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await q.getDocuments();

    print("kjndskjl$products");
    lastDocument = querySnapshot.documents[querySnapshot.documents.length - 1];
    products = querySnapshot.documents;
    
  }
  setState(() => isLoading = false);
}
```

Comment: but getPosts() itself is not returning any data .No i executed a print command n products.The list is elmpty

Comment: I see confused getPosts with getMorePosts, in getPosts does it print print("kjndskjl$products");?

Comment: Yes the list is empty

Comment: and when debugging getFfollowing does foollowingList  is not empty at the end of the method?

Comment: i did this `onPressed: () {print(foollowingList);  print(getPosts());` and it gets the posts and displays on the app.why is it behaving like this?Even after initiating `getPosts()` its not executing without pressing of the button.is it because setState is in forloop?

Comment: maybe the second method getPosts runs before the first because the first uses await in the first line, try changing the Future using getPost inside getFfollowing